# How to store numbers in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, function, methods

I just learned the array function in Java and now I wanted to store numbers from 1-19 in an array but don't know the right way to do it without the userinput function. Here is what I got, can you tell me if it is the right way to store number in array?

```
public class ArrayQuestion1 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int a=0;
       int array[] = new int [20];
       for ( array[a]=1; array[a]<=19; array[a]++){
          System.out.println(array[a]);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? This code uses the first element of the array `array[0]` for all computations, which is probably not what you had in mind. (Variable `a` starts out at 0 and never changes.) However, I can't tell from what you've posted what you _do_ have in mind.

Comment: Unless you want to store `20` in the first element of the array and `0`s in the other elements - no. And even then it's inefficient.

Comment: int array[] = new int [20]; initializes the array (reserves space to store 20 integers). To add a number m to the array at location n, you would use: array[n] = m In your case, you will add the 20 numbers as follows: for (int i =0; i < 20; i++){ array[i] = n //where n is the number you want to add}

Answer (score 3):

You would do something like this to fill your array with consecutive numbers from 0-19

```
public class ArrayQuestion1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array[] = new int [20];
        for (int a = 0; a < array.length; a++){
            array[a] = a;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To store userinputs to int array you can do

```
int array[] = new int [20];
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);

for ( i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    array[i]=scanner.nextInt();
}
```

If you want to store number from 0 to 19 you can do

```
int array[] = new int [20];

for ( i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    array[i]=i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add consecutive numbers you can use a simple for loop and to see them on the screen you can just iterate your array. That is all. Hope this can help you!

```
class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
int a=0;
int array[] = new int [20];
for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++){
    array[i] = i;
 }
 for(int x : array){
   System.out.println(x);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     int array[] = new int[20];
     for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
         array[i] = i;
     }

    //To print all the elements in the array.
    for(int j=1; i< array.length; j++){
        system.out.println(array[j]);
    }   
 }
```

You can insert into the array using the above method and can view the contents of array also.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want user input for array , you have to store numbers manually in the array like ,

```
int a=0;
int array[] = new int [20];
for ( a=1;a<=19; a++){

array[a]=a;

}
```

above code will store 0 to 19 in your array . than you can use below for loop to print it

```
for ( a=1; a<=19; a++){
    System.out.println(array[a]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use an array you have to declare it.

```
int array[] = new int [19];
```

If you want 19 numbers, then use an array with 19 elements.

Then you have to populate each number in the array. To obtain it, just use an index in your array:

```
array[index] = value
```

For example:

```
   for ( int i=0; i<array.lenght; i++){
      array[i] = xx;
   }
```

Pay attention. The first index in your array is 0 (not 1)